# Better Understanding Min Fetch Bytes Within Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Looking at some config I'm tuning for Kafka for batching records to a file.

I see `min fetch bytes` which is the minimum number of bytes returned from a single poll across N partitions of a topic. Here is the scenario I'm concerned about:

I set min fetch to `100mb` worth of record data. Let's say I have `250mb` worth of data. I do two polls and persist `200mb`. Now.. I have `50mb` sitting in the queue, but I still want it to be proccessed, but don't plan of having more data to come in. If the timeout is hit, will it just grab the remaining 50mb?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I should have looked at the docs a bit more closely. Seeing this is used in conjunction with the timeout.

> fetch.max.wait.ms
>
> By setting fetch.min.bytes, you tell Kafka to wait until it has enough
>   data to send before responding to the consumer. fetch.max.wait.ms lets
>   you control how long to wait. By default, Kafka will wait up to 500
>   ms. This results in up to 500 ms of extra latency in case there is not
>   enough data flowing to the Kafka topic to satisfy the minimum amount
>   of data to return. If you want to limit the potential latency (usually
>   due to SLAs controlling the maximum latency of the application), you
>   can set fetch.max.wait.ms to a lower value. If you set
>   fetch.max.wait.ms to 100 ms and fetch.min.bytes to 1 MB, Kafka will
>   receive a fetch request from the consumer and will respond with data
>   either when it has 1 MB of data to return or after 100 ms, whichever
>   happens first.

tl;dr if timeout exceeds before queue is filled, it would just return the remaining 50mb